# What is "->" in a Verilog behavioral model?

Tags: verilog

I'm coding a i2c master module, and I had a Verilog model of AT24C02D provided by Microchip to use in testbench.  I see some "->" in the codes; what does that mean?

Reference:
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MPD/ProductDocuments/BoardDesignFiles/AT24C02D.v

```
//************************************************************************
//********************* S_START and S_STOP conditions ********************
//************************************************************************

// Start trigger allows latency between start condition and falling edge
// of SCL. If stop occurs in this interval the machine ignores the start
// condition and awaits a subsequent start condition.

  // START Condition Detection

  always @ (negedge SDA_in)
  if(SCL == 1) begin
    if (VERBOSE) $display("START condition detected", $time);
    S_STOP = 0;
    S_START = 1;
    -> START_condition;    // Start condition event

    if (VERBOSE) $display ("Got START condtion event");

    @(STOP_condition or negedge SCL)
    if (SCL == 0) begin
      if (VERBOSE) $display ("First negedge of SCL after START", $time);
      Valid_Address_flag = 0;
      if(VERBOSE) $display("START event triggered");
      -> START_trigger;    // Start trigger event
  @ (posedge SCL) S_START = 0;  // Waits until cycle ends
    end
    else begin    // STOP condition detected under same clock
      if (VERBOSE) $display ("STOP under same clock as START");
      S_START = 0;
      S_STOP = 1;
    end
  end
```

I had success compiling the file with `iverilog`.

Answer (score 1):

In the `AT24C02D.v` file in your link, I searched for `START_condition` and discovered this `event` declaration on line 535:

```
event START_condition;
```

The `->` syntax is used to trigger the event.  An event is triggered in zero time; `START_condition` will not be a signal pulse that has any duration.

There are no other uses of `START_condition` in that file; perhaps the code author added it as a waveform debugging aid.  Some waveform viewers will allow you to visually see the time at which an event was triggered.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 6.17 *Event data type*